# Accessing Data From ComboBox in DataGridView Cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have declared a DataGridView (called dataGridView1) in my layout. The cell value I am trying to get is the result of the combobox selection that is in the cell. Based on these two links: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx) and [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747256/datagridview-set-column-cell-combobox) my code looks like this:

```
private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//output data to ResultsText richtextbox to check it
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                ResultsText.Text +="\n"+ cell.Value.ToString();// getting null reference exception here

            }
        }
}
```

My DataGridView code implementation:

```
 private void PopulateDataGridView()
    {
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("LoadCaseCol");

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn lc = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        lc.DataSource = new List<string>() { "opt1", "opt2", "opt3", "opt4" };
        lc.HeaderText = "Select Load Cases";
        //lc.DataPropertyName = "Money";

        //DataGridViewTextBoxColumn name = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        //name.HeaderText = "Name";
        //name.DataPropertyName = "Name";

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        //dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(name, money);
        dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(lc);
    }
```

Comment: The only other piece of error data is: object reference not set to instance of object. Yes I plan to show everything in the textbox for now. I am just testing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get a `NullReferenceException` if `cell.Value` is `null` when you call `ToString()`.

You could use `Convert.ToString()` instead, which specifically checks for `null` and converts it to an empty string (preventing an exception from being thrown):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(Convert.ToString(cell.Value));
    }
}

ResultsText.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the `NullReferenceException` you may use:

```
ResultsText.Text +="\n"+ (cell.Value == null ? "NULL" : cell.Value.ToString());
```

instead of

```
ResultsText.Text +="\n"+ cell.Value.ToString();
```

(assuming that was the problem).

**UPDATED**

The problem might have occured because of the code initializing combo box column.
Please try setting the `DataPropertyName`:

```
private void PopulateDataGridView()
    {
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("LoadCaseCol");

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn lc = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        lc.DataSource = new List<string>() { "opt1", "opt2", "opt3", "opt4" };
        lc.HeaderText = "Select Load Cases";
        lc.DataPropertyName = "LoadCaseCol";

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(lc);
    }
```

Comment: This fixed the error, but Im still not sure why Im having this problem. Any idea what could be causing this?