# Adding a combo Box to a Data grid View

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add a combo Box to the datagrid View. This is the code for the datagrid view

```
           SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT pid, pdtName, amount, Qty,day, cat from purchase where year=@year and month=@month", ConnectionInfo.con);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", comboBox3.Text);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", comboBox2.Text);



            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "number";
            this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "name";
            this.dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "amount";
            this.dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "number";
            this.dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "day";
            this.dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "category";
```

for column 5 in the datagrid view I'm trying to set it as a combo box and read the category names from the category table in my database.

I'm starting with this code but I don't know how to complete it

```
        string query = "select distinct cat from purchase ";
            SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(query, ConnectionInfo.con);

            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
            da2.Fill(ds2, "purchase");

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        cmb.HeaderText = "cat";
        cmb.Name = "cmb";
        cmb.DataSource=ds2
```

Can you point out whats wrong in my code, or help me in another way to solve my problem

Comment: Possibly this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747256/datagridview-set-column-cell-combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format each column using a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn or DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and add it to the DataGridView.  Be sure to set AutoGenerateColumns to false.  Something like:

```
    dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    column.DataPropertyName = "Description";
    column.Name = "Description";
    column.HeaderText = "Description";
    column.Width = 150;
    //column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column)

    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ccolumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    ccolumn.DataPropertyName = "cmb";
    ccolumn.Name = "cmb";
    ccolumn.HeaderText = "Cat";
    ccolumn.Width = 65;
    ccolumn.DataSource = ds2;
    ccolumn.DisplayMember = "cat";
    ccolumn.ValueMember = "cat";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(ccolumn);
```

Do all the columns like this before you assign the DataSource to the DataGridView.

Comment: I tried doing that but all what I get is an empty datagrid Should I change my data source code, I didn't change anything  because I had no problems in it before

Comment: You need to create a new column entry for each column that you want to show.  Do this before you set the datasource of the datagridview.  The DataPropertyName must match a column name in the DataTable.  If this still doesn't work, post the current version of your code and I will look at it.